# Ubuntu ufw Lightsail not opening port 80

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, firewall, aws, ufw

I have port 80 open from AWS lightsail console, and `ufw` status shows that port 80 should be open.

And yet, I cannot `curl` into port 80 nor can I `telnet` or `ping` or launch a server.

I've checked iptables and I can confirm that the rules from ufw apply there. However, when I run `lsof -i -P -n` it does not show any open port 80. Is there another firewall that is blocking 80?

Any help to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated!

Below is the result of `ufw status`

```
5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

And when I run `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep :80` I get nothing returned.

Comment: Not sure. It doesnt seem like it. This question was from march, though. I can’t remember the solution I found. This thread should be closed in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have  SSH TCP 22 on Lightsail-Networking-Firewall. I had https showing on the 'ufw status' command but it would not connect until I added it on Lightsail-Networking-Firewall. (I'm going to see if I can find out if ufw is needed at all)

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between ssh (port 22) and http (port 80)?